# Stuck with two way binding in React JS. I can't able to access two datas with a single button click

Tags: reactjs

I used ternary syntax for the two way bind properties val and initialName,
I've rendered the datas into my button tag which is having the OnClick function

```
class App extends Component{

constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
    val:'Initial value',     
    initialName : 'JonSnow'    
  };
}



onClick = () => {
  const initialName = this.state.initialName 
  === 'JonSnow' ? 'Jax' : 'JonSnow';

  const val = this.state.val === 
  'Initial Value' ? 'Changed' : 'Initial Value';

  return this.setState ( {initialName},{val});
}

render() {


  return (
     <div className='App'> 
     <h1>Hai there ! </h1>
     <p>I am a react paragraph </p>
     <button onClick={this.onClick}>Click Me</button>
     <Program initialName={this.state.initialName}/>
     <Program val= {this.state.val}/>
     </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this.setState accepts an object that will be merged with the current state.

So if you want to override two values, just pass those both in one object:

```
this.setState ( {initialName,val});
```

You do not need to return the setState function call, sicne it will be discarded anyway.

The second parameter of the setState is a callback to be executed once the state is updated.

```
this.setState ( {initialName,val}, () => {THIS WILL BE CALLED ONCE THE STATE IS UPDATED});
```